# CASE where a lot of text needs trimming

Tags: t-sql

I have an output in my queries that gives me:

xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx : 123456 (xx) - xxxxxxx...

or

xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx : 12345678 (xx) - xxxxxxx...

basically text before either a 6 or 8 digit number then text after.

Ideally I'd like to be able to CASE this column so I'd have an output where it's a 6 digit number = London and the output when it's an 8 digit number = Paris.

But I am very stuck on how to get the CASE statement to achieve this - essentially trim out a lot of text, work out if the number is either 6 or 8 digits long, then tell me if it's London or Paris. I'm not sure if it's possible.

Is this sort of CASE statement achievable? Advise / pointers would be very gratefully received. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is using a common table expression with `patindex`.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T As Table
(
    LongText varchar(4000)
)

INSERT INTO @T (LongText) VALUES
('.njauaerigha n uaer gauer 345 gnaehn 123456 (43) smgmshmsrtmh s;s nt;srtn ;nbtugarg '),
('asdfasdfasdf 12345678 (65) asdfag gr 34 6sd 64 fasd fasdfas d fasdfasdf asdf'),
('zxcvzxcvzx34cv zxcvzxcv zxcv zxcv zxcv zcxvz xcv z3 45 xcvzxcz dfg dv df df zfd zdf b 654321 (77)'),
('87654321 (99) n;arng an ; ualerg trhrt srth str sth strh ssth'),
('snhs tgnn ang nu g;arug aegaerlhae s ;5 afnauierhga.ngae489tj 8q3y .sn.5yn b.s n .5hy 5');
```

Then, the common table expression to get the start index of the 8/6 digit number:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT  LongText,
        PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ([0-9][0-9])%', LongText) As Long,
        PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ([0-9][0-9])%', LongText) As Short
FROM @T
)
```

Then, select with a couple of case expressions to extract the number and get the city:

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN Long > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(LongText, Long, 13) 
            WHEN Short > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(LongText, Short, 11) 
        END As Number,
        CASE 
            WHEN Long > 0 THEN 'Paris'
            WHEN Short > 0 THEN 'London'
        END As City,
        LongText
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
Number          City        LongText
123456 (43)     London      .njauaerigha n uaer gauer 345 gnaehn 123456 (43) smgmshmsrtmh s;s nt;srtn ;nbtugarg 
12345678 (65)   Paris       asdfasdfasdf 12345678 (65) asdfag gr 34 6sd 64 fasd fasdfas d fasdfasdf asdf
654321 (77)     London      zxcvzxcvzx34cv zxcvzxcv zxcv zxcv zxcv zcxvz xcv z3 45 xcvzxcz dfg dv df df zfd zdf b 654321 (77)
87654321 (99)   Paris       87654321 (99) n;arng an ; ualerg trhrt srth str sth strh ssth
NULL            NULL        snhs tgnn ang nu g;arug aegaerlhae s ;5 afnauierhga.ngae489tj 8q3y .sn.5yn b.s n .5hy 5
```

Comment: That is incredibly helpful, thank you very much. I apologise for not inputting test data. Can I test your patience with one final question please? Very rarely, but sometimes, I get an output of xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx : TEST12345678 (xx) - xxxxxxx...  where I'd need an output of 'Test'. In the solution above 'Paris' would come through for instances like this. Can I get round this? Apologies for more questions but thanks again.

Comment: I did try:  case 
      when MyColumn like '%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%' then 'Paris'

      when MyColumn like '%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%' then 'London'   else 'Unknown' end as Result  ~~~  but obviously hit the same buffers in these rare TEST instances

Comment: Yes, you can add another column to the cte for the index of `TEST12345678 (xx)`, it's no different than the other two cases in the current answer.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to sort my simpler CASE statement and your more sophisticated response this way. Your help was very much appreciated.